# How to use MockMvc with mock of controller

Tags: java, testing, spring-mvc, mocking, spring-test-mvc

I have this contoller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEvent(Model model,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("myEvent") Event event,
            BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            @RequestParam(required = true) Integer selectedEventTypeId,
            @RequestParam(required = true) Integer selectedEventStatusId) {

        if (result.getErrorCount() > 1 ){
            return "eventDetailsAdd";
        }
        eventService.addEvent(event, selectedEventTypeId, selectedEventStatusId);
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("idEvent", event.getId());
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message", "added correctly at " + new Date() );
        return "redirect:eventDetails";
    }
```

Using mockMvc I want to mock result and check in both varians of `if (result.getErrorCount() > 1 )`

How I can make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `MockMvc`, you cannot. `MockMvc` is a type of HTTP client. You generate your HTTP request with the `MockMvcRequestBuilders`, setup your headers, request parameters, body, and URL. `MockMvc` will mock sending the request integrating the full `DispatcherServlet` stack.

If you want to mock the `BindingResult` argument, I suggest you test your `@Controller` class independently.

```
// in @Test
MyController controller = new MyController(/* maybe other arguments */)
// generate your mocks and declare expectations
controller.addEvent(/* mocks go here */);
// verify your mocks
```

Comment: If I use MockMvc, what result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name(/*what I can expect here?*/))

Comment: @gstackoverflow You can do it that way, but you won't be mocking `BindingResult`. You would have to send request parameters that will make the `Event` argument invalid.

Comment: How I can make Event invalid by http request?

Comment: In debug I see that it is null

Comment: @gstackoverflow It's a long explanation that I don't want to add to this answer because it doesn't directly relate to your question. [Please read this chapter of the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args). Then go read the whole document because there seems to be holes in your understanding.