# How to use MockMvc with mocked repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockmvc, spring-restdocs

**Conext**

- I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406725/how-to-use-mockmvc-with-mock-of-controller) but my problem is different.
- So we are using `Katharsis Controller` and `Spring Data Rest`.
- We only have 1 controller for entire application and then the request will be sent to `Spring Data Rest` repositories classes.
- We want to use `Spring Restdoc` to generate documentation which requires us to write unit tests with `MockMvc`.
- But when using `Mockmvc`, it starts up the container and will require datasources to be set up.
- If we use `standaloneSetup()` and pass the mocked repository class, then `MockMvc` won't load `Katharsis Controller` and therefore the request won't reach that repository.
- I understand that we can create an in-memory database but our project is big and the database needs a huge number of tables to be created we want to avoid that since these tests are for documentation purposes.

**Question**

Is there any way to achieve this and only mock the target repository class?

**Note**

By repository I mean `CrudRepository` interface in `Spring DataRest`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the description of your application. Does your KatharsisContoller handle every request and call various Spring Data repositories or are you also using some controllers that are auto-generated by Spring Data REST? If it's the latter, mocking those auto-generated controllers doesn't sound like a good idea to me as it could lead to your documentation being out of sync with the actual service.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson No the former is the case. So KatharsisController decides what so called json repository to invoke and each json repository calls the related S Data repository. So S.Data repository is at the end and we don't need to test them but we want to mock those repositories.

Comment: It sounds like to need to use `standaloneSetup` and pass in an instance of `KatharsisController` that's been created with the mock repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As Andy Wilkinson suggested, you may consider creating unit test where you wire beans together by yourself and use MokMvc standalone setup.
2. If you want to create integration test and create Spring Context anyway, there is way to fake Spring bean by using `@Primary`, `@ActiveProfiles` and `@Profile` annotations. [I wrote a blog post with GitHub example how to do it](http://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/). You just need to combine this approach with `WebApplicationContext` based `MockMvc` setup. It works without problems, I wrote such tests in the past.